# python cv2 BackgroundSubtractor imshow function error

Tags: python, ffmpeg, opencv3.0

## problem

I want to detect the motional object in a video, but the cap seems not to read the video. I use conda jupyter and have install the ffmpeg with brew and I use macOS. Still, I am unable to capture the video.

## code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.avi')
time.sleep(2)
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN(detectShadows=True)

while(1):
ret, frame = cap.read()

fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

cv2.imshow('original',frame)
cv2.imshow('fg',fgmask)

k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
for c in contours:
        # 获取矩形框边界坐标
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        # 计算矩形框的面积
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if 500 < area < 3000:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("detection", frame)
cv2.imshow("back", dilated)


if k == 27:
    break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### error

Couldn't read video stream from file "test.avi"

Comment: I'm able to run the code after adding `findContours`, maybe some problems with installation? Can u open other videos?

Comment: Not really, I keep getting the error is I try to read video files. But it worked for my embedded camera. the cap.read() returns `false`.

Comment: Maybe try a fresh new conda env and `pip install opencv-python`?

Comment: I tried that already and failed.